# The answer object returns an empty array for tags

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, tags, answers

Since version 2.1, the answer object has a field called `tags`. However, sometimes, an empty array or even nothing is returned in this field:

[Example with the filter `!-*f(6t0Vk01e`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!-*f(6t0Vk01e&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug and seems (based on a series of A/B tests) to be linked with the `body_markdown` property.

That is, if your filter returns the `tags` array, [**it works**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!SWJ_BpAceOT6Ts4Cfr&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

```
"items": [ {
    "tags": [ "batch-file", "cmd" ],
    "answer_id": 42292030
  }, {
    "tags": [ "ios", "arrays", "swift" ],
    "answer_id": 42295110
  },
  etc...
```

, ***unless* [`body_markdown` is also selected](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!1zSk*x-JSjjGQ6oG3r8R-&site=stackoverflow&run=true):**

```
"items": [ {
    "tags": [],
    "answer_id": 42295122,
    "body_markdown": "`ExecuteScalar` fetches the first column value of the first row. So, it won&#39;t make..."
  }, {
    "tags": [],
    "answer_id": 42294953,
    "body_markdown": "The git revert documentation provides the syntax like\r\n\r\n    git revert [--[no-]..."
  },
  etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! Hope this will be fixed, because I need `body_markdown` as well :-/

Comment: was same problem (empty tags field) but solved with excluding *share_link* field from filter

Comment: ```up_vote_count``` and ```down_vote_count``` also seem to have that problem.