# Tags are not returned when querying /users/{ids}/answers

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, tags, answers

I'm querying the API for answers-by-user, and I want the tags belonging to the parent questions.  I seem to be seeing intermittent results: sometimes the `tags` attribute of the response includes the tags, and sometimes it's an empty list.

Is the availability of the `tags` attribute influenced by any other attributes that may or may not be selected in a filter?

For example, this seems to return tags in the result:

- [/2.2/users/147356/answers?page=1&pagesize=2&site=stackoverflow&filter=!bLf7WzPpe-DvjO](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#page=1&pagesize=2&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=147356&filter=!bLf7WzPpe-DvjO&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

While this returns an a `tags` attribute, but it's always an empty list:

- [/2.2/users/147356/answers?page=1&pagesize=2&site=stackoverflow&filter=!bKhRelLgVMFau)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#page=1&pagesize=2&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=147356&filter=!bKhRelLgVMFau)&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Maybe including the `share_link` attribute disables tags?

Also this is not the same as [this related bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/7213/the-answer-object-returns-an-empty-array-for-tags) because:

1. I'm not requesting `body_markdown`.
2. I'm using the `/users/{ids}/answers` route while that was about the straight `/answers` toute.

Comment: This is a bug, one of many filter-related glitches.  Also, neither of your example queries return `tags` for me.  And neither bug is improved in API version 2.3.

Comment: After trying quite a few things, I *suspect* that no filter settings will reliably return `tags` for this route.  The back-end logic is apparently just too busted.